Cannot open "Custom" Propery of ImageList
Im trying to manually set the pictures in a ImageList. When trying to open the "Custom" Property with the 3 dots i get this errormessage:

I tried running
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\REGSVR32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Fm20.dll
in my command prompt, but i get this error when trying to do it:


Did you search for the error code as instructed? If you had you should have found that it means "Could not write key to registry" - your profile is probably not allowed to update the registry
